# To pack an artery

Tags: meaning

In the Seinfeld episode [The Wink](http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheWink.html) there is following dialogue:

> JERRY: What is [Holly] making?
>
> ELAINE: I don't know. But I'm sure it had,... parents. Call her up. She won't mind if you come.
>
> JERRY: Oh, don't worry. I'll be there and I'll be packing an artery.

Jerry is on a vegetarian diet and Holly - Elaine's relative, whom Jerry is courting - likes to prepare meals from meat. The last phrase probably means that Jerry will eat Holly's meals despite the diet.

What does **packing an artery** mean?

I have an image of a wild animal (e. g. a wolf), who is eating a cow and cutting its arteries with his teeth. Jerry could mean that he'll devour whatever Holly makes with the same passion as that wolf.

Comment: "Packing a weapon" means carrying a firearm.  By analogy, "packing an artery" means he'll be carrying a spare artery.  (Not really carrying one, but the implication is that he would if he could.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beef has a lot of cholesterol which clogs arteries.  Jerry is either saying he is going to eat so much that his arteries are going to be considered "packed" or that he is going to bring an extra artery so that he can eat a lot of fatty food.

Comment: I always understood it as the first. Why he didn't say he'd be packing arteries (plural), though, I don't know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "bring an extra artery" is the correct sense.

Comment: I think it's the former.  Eating so much fatty food that your arteries will be clogged (packed).